# Make element above grid be the same width as grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like the search input above the grid to be the same size as the grid.  When you load this up initially on a device with a large enough resolution, they look the same, but when you start making the browser viewport smaller, so that only one card fits per row, the grid becomes smaller, however, the above div that contains the search input does not. I'd like to make the search div reactive so that it would resize for users with smaller resolutions would.

Perhaps there is some way to actually put in in the grid, I just don't know how to do this.

I have created the following codepen as an example:

https://codepen.io/latchkostov/pen/vYOVjjo

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(450px, 450px));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  grid-area: auto / auto;
}

.search-input {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search-input" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">Card 1</div>
    <div class="item">Card 2</div>
    <div class="item">Card 3</div>
    <div class="item">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **I would like the search input above the grid be the same size as the grid** this is actually what your code is doing, i don't understand the end result here, If you want the item to be the same size as the search when there's only one per row change to `minmax(450px, 1fr)`

Comment: you may reset values og grid-template-columns to  `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));` so it fits better the screen while shrinking   https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abORjzd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct but few thing is missing. You use `box-sizing: border-box;` with `.content` class property `margin: 20px 20px;` it will create issue in smaller devices. `.content` should be `margin: 0 auto;` and `padding: 20px 15px;`. You use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(450px, 450px));`. It will not work for smaller devices where device size smaller than `450px` you will see horizontal scroll bar. You can use `@media` to rewrite `grid` property. Below I'm modify your `css` property and `HTML` in snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* height: 100%; */ /* You no need to use height 100% here. It have no effect */
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* height: 100%; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .grid{
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  /* grid-area: auto / auto; */
}

.search-input {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .search-input{
    max-width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search-input" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"><div class="item">Card 1</div></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><div class="item">Card 2</div></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><div class="item">Card 3</div></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><div class="item">Card 4</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the layout work with a few modifications to your code:

- Switch from `column` to `row wrap` in the flex container.
- Set both the search bar and the grid to 100% width of the container.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/sostupid555/pen/KKpGGmR)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.search {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-width: 450px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.search-input {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search-input" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">Card 1</div>
    <div class="item">Card 2</div>
    <div class="item">Card 3</div>
    <div class="item">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get size from your grid card as 'width' and set size to your above div.

here the following javascript.

```
<script>
   //Get one card from the grid
   var card1 = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0];
   //Get width of this card
   var card1Width = card1.offsetWidth;
    //Get your search div
    var searchDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('searchDiv')[0];
    //set the card's width on search div
     searchDiv.style.width = card1Width+"px";   
</script>
```

Comment: Trying to handle this with strictly CSS.  No JS should be required here.